# How to Convert DATETIME to CHAR in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to convert a MS SQL date time a specific format:

```
MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM AMPM
```

which means that the HH has to have a leading zero if necessary: `03:25 PM` instead of `3:25 PM`.

Also, there should be a space between the minutes and either AM or PM.

I couldn't find one of the convert codes to match this.

In case it matters, this is SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR,GETDATE(),101) + ' ' + 
     CASE SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,GETDATE(),100),13,1) WHEN ' ' THEN '0' ELSE SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,GETDATE(),100),13,1) END +
     SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,GETDATE(),100),14,4) + ' ' + RIGHT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,GETDATE(),100),2)
```

Might I also suggest this code:

```
 DECLARE @OFDate DATETIME

 SET @OFDate = DATEADD(hh,13,GETDATE())

 SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@OFDate,101) + ' ' + 
 CASE SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@OFDate,100),13,1) WHEN ' ' THEN '0' ELSE SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@OFDate,100),13,1) END +
 SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@OFDate,100),14,4) + ' ' + RIGHT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@OFDate,100),2)
```

which you can use to offset the current date to prove that it works for multiple cases. For instance, when I use the numbers 0, 1, 12 and 13 right now, I get:

04/18/2016 09:34 AM
04/18/2016 10:34 AM
04/18/2016 09:34 PM
04/18/2016 10:34 PM

which means you can probably guess my time zone.

This is pretty cumbersome code. I don't know if you can do any better or not, but it will hopefully get you started. I suggest that if you are going to be needing this in a lot of places, but without a whole lot of access in your procedure, that you could use a function to return it. If you're going to be doing it for lots of different lines in a table, though, you're better off just to put the unelegant, complicated code right into your procedure.

Answer (score 4):

Use the new FORMAT function:

```
DECLARE @dt DATETIME = '2016-04-18 15:05:22'

SELECT FORMAT(@dt, 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt')
-- output: 04/18/2016 03:05 PM
```

Available from SQL Server 2012.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634398.aspx
Examples: http://sqlhints.com/2013/06/23/format-string-function-in-sql-server-2012/

Comment: Uh, yeah. That's way better than mine. Upvoting that one. Ignore mine unless you really want to do some custom thing that isn't available using the FORMAT.

Comment: This would be beautiful. However, I'm getting a `'FORMAT' is not a recognized built-in function name` and I'm in 2008 R2 :-(

Comment: Turns out that it is only available from SQL 2012 after all; sorry for that, and updated the answer. Not a good answer for your situation, but still useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

[CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: I am using CONVERT but none of the codes for the formats result in the specific format that I need.

Comment: @Amarundo is the format you need a standard format? if no, then use DATEPART and construct your own.

Comment: DATEPART doesn't give me an option for AM/PM, I believe. But well, I can do that with `RIGHT(oneoftheformats,2)`

Comment: I meant JUST AM/PM. Doesn't look like from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx. Thanks, regardless.

Comment: Seriously? comon man, use your imagination. SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length ) , Start? well... LENGHT -2 , because AM/PM is always two chars and always at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT (VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 101) + ' ' + CONVERT (VARCHAR,CONVERT (TIME, GETDATE()))
```

or

change the language setting in your session with

```
SET LANGUAGE us_english

SELECT * FROM sys.syslanguages
```

Comment: This one give me the seconds too and it's in military format. I didn't try with setting the language, though.

Answer (score 0):

With Microsoft Sql Server:

```
--
-- Create test case
--
DECLARE @myDateTime DATETIME
SET @myDateTime = '2016-04-03'

--
-- Convert string
--
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @myDateTime, 120), 10)
```